# Advise on a bag for Nikon lens 70-200 2.8

Tags: nikon-d90, camera-bag

Got myself a Nikon 70-200mm f2.8 lens. Its a big lens and I'm looking to find a comfortable case for it. I also have Nikon D90.  So preferably I can fit both body and lens into one case.

I'm looking for something compact that I can easily carry around. Currently I have Lowepro100 (which fits my d90 + 18-200 lens) and I like it. Maybe something along those lines.

Comment: What style of bag are you looking for?  Shoulder bag?  Backpack?  Belt system?  Other?

Comment: I think you could do with expanding on this a little.

What other gear do you want to carry? 
What do you shoot mostly?
What kind of solution are you looking for? (shoulder, backpack, solid case, carry on compatible etc)?

Answer (score 2):

I use Tamrac bags, and prefer the holster-style bags.

Their version that would fit a DSLR and 70-200 lens is the [Pro Digital Zoom 10](http://www.tamrac.com/5630.htm).

My favorite part of their system is the [MAS Accessory system](http://www.tamrac.com/g_modularaccessory.htm), which allows you to hook on extra lens bags.